# How can I ping a password protected Redis server using netcat in an initContainer?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, redis, netcat, kubernetes-pod

Note: solution can use netcat or any other built-in Linux utility

I need to implement an initContainer and liveness probe that confirms my redis pod is up for one of my redis dependent pods. I have attempted the netcat solution offered as the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243121/abuse-curl-to-communicate-with-redis) (`(printf "PING\r\n"; sleep 1) | nc 10.233.38.133 6379`) but I get `-NOAUTH Authentication required.` error in response. Any way around this? I am aware I could install redis-cli or make a management command in my Django code but would prefer not to. Nor do I want to implement a web server for my Redis instance and use curl command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could always send in your `AUTH` command as part of your probe, like:

```
`"AUTH ....\r\nPING\r\n"`
```

Unless you're getting `INFO` from the server, you don't seem to care about the nature of the response, so no auth is required, just test for `NOAUTH`.

Comment: good idea but what i also want to confirm the password is correct

Comment: That's why I'm suggesting adding a new line in there.

Comment: accepted as answer. final solution `(printf "AUTH <password>\r\n"; sleep 1) | nc <redis IP> 6379`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the initContainers stanza that you can use:

```
  initContainers:
    - name: wait-for-redis
      image: busybox
      command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - >
        set -x;
        until ((printf "AUTH <password>\r\n"; sleep 1) | nc <redis-host> 6379);
        do echo waiting for redis;
        sleep 2; done
```

Just don't forget to change `<redis-host>` and `<password>` to their values.