# Redis script for memory flush

Tags: redis

Is it possible to create a script for Redis that flush its memory when it is above a certain value?
In my specific case, I want a flush when the memory is above 90%.
What is the best way, via bash script or Lua script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Abuse cURL to communicate with Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243121/abuse-curl-to-communicate-with-redis)

Comment: this doesn't answer me. Maybe for more information, I'm using GCP Memorystore

Comment: If I use `(printf "MEMORY STATS\r\n";) | nc REDIS_IP 6379` I obtain all the values. Is there a way to see only a field? I'm looking for something like a `grep`

Comment: Maybe this command is more useful `redis-cli -h REDIS_IP -p 6379 memory stats` than the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Lua script as it will perform faster, atomically, and it would be easy to use both from redis-cli and any application code.

Here a Lua script to get memory used and `maxmemory`, the percent, and an action placeholder. It uses both `MEMORY STATS` and `INFO memory` to illustrate.

`MEMORY STATS` brings structured information, but doesn't include `maxmemory` or `total_system_memory`, as `INFO memory` does. `CONFIG GET` is not allowed from Lua scripts.

```
local stats = redis.call('MEMORY', 'STATS')
local memused = 0
for i = 1,table.getn(stats),2 do
    if stats[i] == 'total.allocated' then
        memused = stats[i+1]
        break
    end
end
local meminfo = redis.call('INFO', 'memory')
local maxmemory = 0
for s in meminfo:gmatch('[^\\r\\n]+') do
    if string.sub(s,1,10) == 'maxmemory:' then
        maxmemory = tonumber(string.sub(s,11))
    end
end
local mempercent = memused/maxmemory
local action = 'No action'
if mempercent > tonumber(ARGV[1]) then
    action = 'Flush here'
end
return {memused, maxmemory, tostring(mempercent), action}
```

Use as:

```
> EVAL "local stats = redis.call('MEMORY', 'STATS') \n local memused = 0 \n for i = 1,table.getn(stats),2 do \n     if stats[i] == 'total.allocated' then \n     memused = stats[i+1] \n break \n end \n end \n local meminfo = redis.call('INFO', 'memory') \n local maxmemory = 0 \n for s in meminfo:gmatch('[^\\r\\n]+') do \n     if string.sub(s,1,10) == 'maxmemory:' then \n     maxmemory = tonumber(string.sub(s,11)) \n end \n end \n local mempercent = memused/maxmemory \n local action = 'No action' \n if mempercent > tonumber(ARGV[1]) then \n     action = 'Flush here' \n end \n return {memused, maxmemory, tostring(mempercent), action}" 0 0.9
1) (integer) 860264
2) (integer) 100000000
3) "0.00860264"
4) "No action"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the way to obtain the allocated memory `redis-cli -h 1.2.3.4 -p 6379 memory stats | sed -n 4p`. Now it's easy to create a bash script